# Google App Script Web App: Getting error while signed in a google account

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzRK7_7-zspDtSAY_mVSrqP01e0H_Hlef97h4gjK8lCnt9-v1mhLBGPIuZ4ZE5uqk96yw/exec?test=22

I have deployed my app script as web app like this and the link above is its URL. It simply returns all GET parameters.
[image]

I think you all should be able to see the result of above link. However, when I open it in my browser while logged in my personal google account, I get this error screen

[image]

And I tried this with my other google account, there is no error.

Very strange. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Ideally, it should work. 
Can you clear your browser cookies and try again?

Comment: Actually I log in my personal account in another browser and am able to open the page. What I don't understand is what could have been causing this error?

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cookies and again logging in with the same account with which you were getting the error to see if it's resolved?

Comment: any outcome to this one? It keeps hunting me!